# MVC2 C#: How can I populate a contentplaceholder with html from a file?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-partialview

So.. The issue I have came across is I am migrating a client's web app to MVC2, and the original method for displaying html content is not capable of working with MVC so I am needing to update it. The functionality I need is like so: There is a side nav that will contain the actions, and say the user clicks on "FooBar" it will populate the "mainContent" placeholder with the "FooBar.html" file from a document directory. I would like to do this with no postbacks as well if it is possible. Any ideas?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load/ is your shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use jQuery ajax to load the pages when user clicks on the link. [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function will be ideal here.

It is just `HTML` and `javascript`. Nothing specific to ASP.NET MVC

```
//Include jQuery library
<div>
  <a href="Home/about" class="aLink" >About</a>
  <a href="Home/FAQ" class="aLink" >FAQ</a>
  <a href="Home/Contact" class="aLink" >Contact</a>
</div>
<div id="mainContent">


</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
    $("a.aLink").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();  // prevent the default navigation behaviour
       $("#mainContent").load($(this).attr("href"));
    });
 });

</script>
```